# Invalid use of type "object" as a Firestore argument

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm adding data to my Firestore collection with [node-red-contrib-cloud-firestore](https://npmjs.org/package/node-red-contrib-cloud-firestore). Everything went well until I decided to add a nested array in my data:

```
{ firstname: 'John',
  contact:
   { name: 'Jane Doe',
     company: 'Inc',
     mail: 'jdoe@inc.com' },
  name: 'Doe',
  email: 'johndoe@inc.com' }
```

The code in the [module](https://github.com/sichangi/node-red-contrib-cloud-firestore/blob/master/src/Write/WriteNode.js#L47) goes

```js
this.firestore.collection(col).add(payload)
```

I double-checked the payload, everything is exactly like the one above, but the error show

```
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Invalid use of type "object" as a Firestore argument (found in field contact).
```

Is there a trick I need to know about nested objects?

Thanks

Comment: "An array cannot contain another array value as one of its elements." : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/data-types - not possible?

Comment: Thank you but that's an object, a.k.a. a map, that's a valid type according to your link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem comes from NodeRED functions running in a VM and copying all the prototypes resulting in the strict equality fail.

The workaround is to create the object outside of NodeRED functions. More details by NodeRED lead [here](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/payload-and-js-plain-object/12100)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add a nested map and not a nested array, that is supported by Firestore.

Are you certain that the 'contact' field is not `undefined` when trying to set the doc?

Comment: Yes I checked that. But after some exploration, it fails the `isPlainObject` check of the Firestore serializer because `Object.getPrototypeOf(input) === Object.prototype` is `false` but I don't understand why

Comment: You may have seen this issue: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/143 - Have you tried converting the nested object into a plain objects before sending?

Comment: Yes, a JSON.parse/stringify do the trick for the nested object. Not the cleanest option but it works. I think the problem must come from NodeRED doing stuff with the payload